# Equivalent individuals to classes

Tags: owl, protege

What does it mean to set an individual as "equivalent to" a subclass or class? Why not to keep the individuals for that subclass as normal individuals? (I mean as instances of that class, without setting them as equivalent to it.)

Comment: That can be useful in cases where you can enumerate the individuals of a class. I.e., I could have a class `WeekDay` and set it equivalent to `{Mo,  Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun}. The value is that reasoners know there is no other individuals that exist for `WeekDay` besides those listed and the individuals `Mo`,  `Tue`, `Wed`, `Thu`, `Fri`, `Sat`, `Sun` are instances of `WeekDay`. However, do not need to say a set of individuals are equivalent to a class. It is only necessary if the use case requires it and the number of individuals can be enumerated.

Comment: As Henriette said, this could be a case of a class containing a limited number of individuals (or one, in the case you describe), but it could also be a case of punning (i.e., an individual and a class identified by the same IRI). This is used when there are assertions about the class "as if" it was an individual. Classical example is the Eagle class of all eagles and the Eagle individual which is of type Species. Can you add more details to your example, to distinguish which situation you're in?

Comment: Thanks, that was usefull.

Comment: In this case, it is important to set the individuals as "equivalent to" class. In the example i use yes, the individuals are limited to a set of examples ( so it is good to set them as equivalent to their class. Also, in some cases, I have one subclass that will have only one individual so I set it as equivalent to that subclass. (is that right also? )